# Ruby method returns nil value after executing a condition

Tags: ruby, return-value

I have the following method

```
def add_5(a)
   a + 5 
end
```

when I call **add_5(5)** it returns **10**

for the method

```
def add_5(a)
   a + 5 
   a + 5 if false 
end
```

when I call **add_5(5)** it returns **nil**.
I just need to know why this happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just need to know why this happens

- Implicit return value of a method is a value of its last evaluated expression.
- Your last evaluated expression is an `if`.
- Value of an `if` expression is a last evaluated expression in the corresponding body ("if block" or "else block", depending on how condition evaluates).
- That `if` didn't evaluate its truthy body (due to its falsey condition) and it doesn't have a falsey body, so it has no value. In such cases, `nil` is normally returned.

Comment: Nitpicking, but the return value is the value of the last _evaluated_ expression. It doesn't have to be the expression before the method's `end`.

Answer (score 3):

This line: `a + 5 if false` is so-called postfix conditional operator, or postfix condition.

All the conditional operators, including, but not limited to `if`, `unless`, `case` do return `nil` if the condition(s) were not matched.